# New index in Kibana with +18000 fields causes problems

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana

We have been running ElasticSearch v. 1.6.0 and Kibana v. 4.1.0 with NGINX as proxy in production for about two months now and the set-up handles logging of multiple applications. 
We have 830.000 documents, total of 450MB and a single node. All log statements get shipped to ElasticSearch using Serilog, which creates an index per day.

A week ago Kibana started being extremely slow. I think that I've finally figured out the reason; upon creating the index in Kibana, we did not check the box "Use event times to create index names", thus I guess that even though we only query log statements which has occurred within the last 15 minutes, then Kibana actually asks ElasticSearch to look in all indices.

Thus, I created a new index in Kibana with the format [serilog-]YYYY.MM.DD and Kibana acknowledged that the pattern followed all the existing indices.
However, it found more than 18000 fields in the indices. And many of the fields looks like

```
fields.modelState.Value.Value.Culture.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.IsReadOnlye
```

(where `IsReadOnly` varies from field to field, and likewise do the number of nested `Parent`).

It seems like this is causing problems, because when I go to the Discover tab, then I get a JavaScript error in the Console:

[image]

Notice how `indexPattern.fields` is undefined. And after this error, I receive a 413:

[image]

And Kibana looks like

[image]

These fields weren't in our old index (which had the format serilog-*). I guess it's because the fields first appeared in log statements after our initial deployment to production.

**Update**

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/.kibana/index-pattern/_search'` yields

[image]

However, under the Settings tab I can see

[image]

I do not need all those fields with pattern

`fields.modelState.Value.Value.Culture.Parent.`

Comment: Can you look at .kibana index whether respective index-pattern you are talking about is successfully created or not? You can get all index-patterns created in Kibana by executing following curl request: 
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/.kibana/index-pattern/_search'

Comment: Hmm, the index pattern is created. I've added the result of the GET in the post. But the weird thing is that the pattern with _id [serilog-]YYYY.MM.DD doesn't have any fields node under _source.

Comment: I managed to get the index-pattern created by setting indexPattern:fieldMapping:lookBack to 1, which resulted in about 900 fields. 
However, whenever I access the Discover tab in Kibana, I can see in the Console that

GET http://venlog01.em.dk/elasticsearch/.kibana/_mapping/*/field/_source?_=1455873980772 502 (Bad Gateway)
failure in 120219.53ms

and just after

Error: Bad Gateway
    at respond (index.js?_b=7467:85279)